# Solving a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $(\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,)^\textrm{t} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $S = S^\textrm{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ with
$$\alpha + (\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,)\,S\, \left(\begin{matrix}u \\ v \\ w\end{matrix}\right)= 0 \hspace{0.2in} \textrm{whenever} \hspace{0.2in} u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1.$$
Note that 't' denotes matrix transpose. Show that $$S = -\alpha I,$$ where $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

Comment: Do you want to say that $\alpha + (\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,)\,S\, \left(\begin{matrix}u \\ v \\ w\end{matrix}\right)= 0$ is true for all $(\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,)$ with $u^2+v^2+w^2=1$?

Comment: That's correct. I clarified my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \alpha + (\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,)\,S\, \left(\begin{matrix}u \\ v \\ w\end{matrix}\right)= 0 $$

By  $ x \cdot Ay = A^Tx \cdot y $

$$ \alpha + \,S\,^T(\,u \ \ v \ \ w\,) \left(\begin{matrix}u \\ v \\ w\end{matrix}\right)= 0 $$

By $ u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1 $ and associatvity

$$ \alpha + \,S\,^T = 0  $$

By $ S = S^T $

$$ \alpha + \,S\ = 0  $$

wrapping things up

$$ \alpha I + \,S\ I = 0 I  $$

$$  S = -\alpha I $$

Comment: Why does $x \cdot Ay = A^\textrm{t} x \cdot y$?

Comment: I hope you see that $ x \cdot y = x^Ty $ , then $ x \cdot Ay = Ay \cdot x = (Ay)^Tx = (y^TA^T)x = y^T(A^Tx) = y \cdot A^Tx = A^Tx \cdot y $.